# Calculate Coefficient of Variance and null observations being exceptions

Tags: r

I have a data set say (4,5,6,7) and I am trying to figure out the Coefficient of variance using "cv" function in R. I want to add a logic where I want to calculate Cv for datasets where the first value isn't NULL.

Hence I would want to calculate cv of (4,5,6,7) and not (NULL,1,2,3)

Comment: We can use `is.null`, but I think if you have a vector, then I don't see the possibility of NULL value.  Perhaps you have a missing value i.e. `NA`?

Comment: yes lets say its a missing value in the set. I tried to use is.null but didn't work.

Comment: In that case, you can use `is.na`

Comment: > data<-c(NA,2,3,4,5)
> if (!is.na(data)) {cv(data)}
Warning message:
In if (!is.na(data)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used

Comment: because `if/else` is not vectorized.  In your original question, it was like the if the first value is not NA. i.e. `if(!is.na(data[1]))`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `if` with `is.na`

```
f1 <- function(x) if(!is.na(x[1])) cv(x)  else NA
f1(data)
f1(data1)
```

#### data

```
data <- 4:7
data1 <- c(NA, 1:3)
```